# How to change the background colour of a UICollectionViewCell based on a given value

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller which contains a `UICollectionView`. It has re-use identifier `ValveCell` specified for the prototype cell.  It is using a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell called ValveViewCell.

I have put a couple of text labels on the prototype cell using the Storyboard and I can get the different values to display in multiple cells no problem. There are currently 4 cells, displaying info from 4 different valves.

All I want to do is change the background colour of the cell depending on whether the valve is turned on or off (a boolean value which I can successfully test on).

I am using this code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ValveViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ValveCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  Valve *valve = [valveArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.valveID.text = [valve.valveID stringValue];
  cell.valveLabel.text = valve.valveLabel;
  cell.valveStatus.text = valve.status;

  if ([valve isOn]) {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
  } else {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

The problem is that it does change the background colour, but it changes every single cell's background colour instead of just the current cell.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by current cell?? Is it selected cell?

Comment: `[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];`

Comment: What I meant was that as it iterates through each item in the array, it should change the colour of the specific UICollectionViewCell according to a valve that's set for that specific cell.  It turned out that actually it was nothing to do with the UICollectionViewCell at all, it was a bad value that it was basing the logic on.  Since the value was actually always returning nil, it was changing every cell to the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Fix! Put this as the first line in your method!

```
ValveViewCell *cell = [[ValveViewCell alloc] init]
```

and then change

```
ValveViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ValveCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ValveCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You're referencing the same cell for the whole collectionView so initializing each cell will fix your issue.